# aggregate records with or without sub array records

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I can't success to extract all main records and eventually arrays. I only extract main records fields with "attributes" count > 0.

Data sample is :

```
docs = [ 
    { docId : "1", fieldDoc1: "value", fieldDoc2: "value", attributes: [ { attrId: "1.1", fieldAttr1: "value" }, { attrId: "1.2", fieldAttr1: "value" }] },
    { docId : "2", fieldDoc1: "value", fieldDoc2: "value", attributes: [ { attrId: "2.1", fieldAttr1: "value" }] },
    { docId : "3", fieldDoc1: "value", fieldDoc2: "value", attributes: [ ] }
    ];

db.table.aggregate ( 
    { $match: { criterias on main part fields }, 
    { $unwind: "attributes" }, 
    { $match: { criteria on attributes fields },
    { $group : { 
            _id : "$docId", 
            "docs": { 
                "$push": { 
                    "_id": "$docId", 
                    "fieldDoc1": "$fieldDoc1", 
                    "fieldDoc2": "$fieldDoc2",
                    "attributes": "$attributes"}
                }
        } } );
```

For exemple, for extracting all records, I try :

```
db.table.aggregate ( 
        { $unwind: "attributes" }, 
        { $group : { 
                _id : "$docId", 
                "docs": { 
                    "$push": { 
                        "_id": "$docId", 
                        "fieldDoc1": "$fieldDoc1", 
                        "fieldDoc2": "$fieldDoc2",
                        "attributes": "$attributes"}
                    }
            } } );
```

and I only get docId:"1" and docId:"2" with their attributes.
docId:"3" which has no attributes is not returned.

1) So how to get all corresponding records, with or without attributes;

2) how to get all fields of the main part, without enumerating them literaly (fieldDoc1:"$fieldDoc1", fieldDoc2":"$fieldDoc2", etc...

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I found is to update mongo to release 3.2 and then use $unwind:{path: ,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`$exists: true` will match those documents where the field exists even if it is null or empty.

```
db.table.aggregate (
    { $match: { attributes : { $exists: true }} }, 
    { $unwind: "attributes" }, 
    { $group : { 
            _id : "$docId", 
            "docs": { 
                "$push": { 
                    "_id": "$docId", 
                    "fieldDoc1": "$fieldDoc1", 
                    "fieldDoc2": "$fieldDoc2",
                    "attributes": "$attributes"}
                }
        } } );
```

Comment: Euh, this doesn't works for me. I think that solution is delivered by mongodb 3.2, with options : $unwind:{path: <field path>,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}. But I can't update my framework.